# use of package bbold and mathbb at same time

Tags: fonts, amsmath

Using the package `bbold` changes the look of `\mathbb{R}` which I dont want. However, I do want the look of `\mathbb{1}` from the package `bbold`. Is there some way to have both or am I too greedy :)

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\usepackage{bbold}   <------ CHANGE HERE
    
\begin{document}    

    $\mathbb{1}$
    
        $\mathbb{R}$
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have restrict your MWE (for example

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

are strange). You can declare a `\DeclareMathAlphabet` using the `1` of `bbbold` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbb}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\begin{document}    
$\mathbbb{1}$, $\mathbb{R}$
    
\end{document}
```

[image]